# Strange error when generating method with a macro?

Tags: methods, macros, clojure

Here's a short snippet that demonstrates the problem:

```
(defmulti test-dummy type)

(defmacro silly [t]
  `(defmethod test-dummy ~(resolve t) [some-arg] "FOO!"))

(silly String)
```

Evaluating this results in "Can't use qualified name as parameter: user/some-arg", but running macroexpand gives a perfectly good result:

```
(defmethod test-dummy java.lang.String [some-arg] "FOO!")
```

Typing ~' before the argument name to make it evaluate into a symbol works, but what is going on?

Comment: Probably you can use autogensym to avoid this. change `some-arg` to `some-arg#` in your macro definition.

Comment: Alright, but why does this happen? And why do I get the correct expression from macroexpand?

Comment: Sadly, the `macroexpand` function is not 100% compatible with the compiler. That said, I do not see the same macroexpansion you do: `(. user/test-dummy clojure.core/addMethod java.lang.String (clojure.core/fn [user/some-arg] "FOO!"))` - this namespace qualifies `some-arg`, which is the expected and documented behavior of `

Comment: @noisesmith: You're right. There seems to be an issue with the CIDER REPL for emacs. The documentation states that C-c C-m invokes macroexpand-1, but calling it manually returns a different result, the same one you got. I suppose both mysteries are solved.

Comment: I have stopped being surprised by anything weird from cider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. So the issue here is that Clojure attempts to enfoce [macro hygiene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro) by ensuring that no symbols in a macro's expansion are unqualified locals which could capture from the macro's expansion environment.

Traditionally, Lisp dialects have allowed macro expansions to contain arbitrary symbols. This creates issues where the expression containing a macro to be expanded defines a symbol `some-arg` which is used without definition in the expanded result of the macro. This means that the macro is "capturing" a symbol/value from its expansion environment which is rarely desired behavior. This is exactly what the Clojure compiler thinks is going on here with your symbol `some-arg`. The Clojure compiler attempts to resolve `some-arg` to a namespace level symbol (a previous definition or require creating an alias to the symbol some-var) and it fails to do so thus generating the warning that `user/some-arg` is undefined.

There are two cannonical solutions to this problem. The first is to use a gensym for `some-arg` which the macro expansion system knows denotes a local and will not attempt to resolve.

```
(defmacro silly [t]
  `(defmethod test-dummy ~(resolve t) [some-arg#] "FOO!"))
```

The other method is that you can use the macro splice operator `~` to insert the value of a quoted symbol.

```
(defmacro silly [t]
  `(defmethod test-dummy ~(resolve t) [~'some-arg] "FOO!"))
```

In both cases you have to use the same expression (either the gensym or the splice) at all uses of the symbol. The gensym will as the name suggests generate a symbol for use and thus will not produce repeatable naming. This is a feature for escaping symbol collisions. The splice however will enable you to always generate a specified symbol in case you need a real human-usable name for something (say a def) or you actually do want to close over something from the environment explicitly.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thank you. I was under the incorrect impression that the backtick works the same way as in Common Lisp.